# How to reduce the statement and resultset objects ? ??

Tags: java, scope

I want to collect following 12 metrics(TotalEmail,SentEmail,etc). For that I am using a local method(getValues()). In that I am using 12 Statement and ResultSet objects. It is working fine. Can you suggest me any other way to reduce memory usage for variables.

getValues() {

```
private Statement TotalEmail    =   null;
private Statement SentEmail     =   null;
private Statement FailEmail     =   null;   
private Statement ActiveUser    =   null;
private Statement FailLogin     =   null;
private Statement SentLogin     =   null;   
private Statement TotalBilling  =   null;
private Statement FailBilling   =   null;
private Statement SuccessBilling=   null;
private Statement TotalSubmission   =   null;
private Statement FailSubmission    =   null;
private Statement SuccessSubmission =   null;

private ResultSet TotalEmailRS  =   null;
private ResultSet SentEmailRS   =   null;
private ResultSet FailEmailRS   =   null;
private ResultSet ActiveUserRS  =   null;
private ResultSet FailLoginRS   =   null;
private ResultSet SentLoginRS   =   null;
private ResultSet TotalBillingRS    =   null;
private ResultSet FailBillingRS     =   null;
private ResultSet SuccessBillingRS  =   null;
private ResultSet TotalSubmissionRS =   null;
private ResultSet FailSubmissionRS  =   null;
private ResultSet SuccessSubmissionRS   =   null;
```

}

Comment: This is not your real code. You can't have `private` keyword inside a method. These look like instance variables, and instance variables don't need to be explicitly initialized to `null` since they already are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution:

Instead of creating a specific mysql query for each query, can you adapt your code so that you have only one query function?

I would do it this way:

```
//As 'parameters' I would write String colMatch, but you adapt it to your needs
private String getTotalEmail( ...parameters... ){ 
    return getDataMysql(column, table, colMatch);
}

private String getDataMysql(String column, String table, String colMatch){
          PreparedStatement query = null;
          ResultSet rs = null;
          String data = "";
          try{
            String queryQ = "SELECT " + column + " FROM " + table +
                    " WHERE " + column + " = '" + colMatch + "' ";
            query = Connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(queryQ);
            rs = query.executeQuery(queryQ);

            //if you know there will be only one possible value found
            while ( rs.next() ){
                data = rs.getString(column);
            }          
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Error query getDataMysql");
        }finally{
            // code for closing connection
        }
        return data;
    }
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot. I got the answer. This way is really Cool. But One doubt, Whether it will degrade any performance ?